# How does tf.layers.batch_normalization calculate mean and variance during test time? (test data has machine-generated samples)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I am trying to implement batch-normalization on my CNN that currently applies dropout. One problem is that I do not know how the mean and variance are calculated during test time.

On the documentation it says that if training=False is set then the normalization is done with moving statistics. What does this mean?

In addition, since my test data has lots of machine-generated samples I cannot use population mean and variance and just apply tf.nn.batch_normalization(). These samples are used to prevent hand labeling and are excluded when scoring my model

Comment: BN stores the running mean and var into variables during training and simply uses them in testing

Comment: @Maxim I added the BN layers to my network. But now my network overfits the training set 99.8% and validation accuracy stays at 40% after few epochs. Shouldn't the batch normalization reduce the overfitting not the other way around? I added BN to try to combat my mild overfitting but now it is 2x times worse xD

Comment: That's a completely different question ;) Well, it should...